# What to use instead of AssertJ isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields?

Tags: assertj

This method seems to be Deprecated.
I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what AssertJ advises to use instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As mentioned in the [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String...)):

> Use the recursive comparison by calling [`usingRecursiveComparison()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#usingRecursiveComparison()) and chain with [`ignoringFields(String...)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringFields(java.lang.String...)).
>
> This method is deprecated because it only compares the first level of fields while the recursive comparison traverses all fields recursively (only stopping at java types).

```
assertThat(oneObject)
    .usingRecursiveComparison()
    .ignoringFields("fieldToIgnore")
    .isEqualTo(anotherObject);
```